# Textbox retaining original value

Tags: jquery, css

Please refer [this](http://jsfiddle.net/shrikanth/cBg52/4/)

Steps: click on div with pink color, black color div opens with three text boxes in it.
        Default focus will be on first textbox having values'a'.
        Now user enters some value to second and third text box and step off (moves away)this div.
        Again click on div with pink color and div with black color opens with all three text boxes filled with some value. Is there any way(Other than page reload) can we stop displaying values to second and third text box. In otherwords second and third text box should contain original value (in this case it should have been empty)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#xxx").click(function () {

    $("#aaa").show();
    $('#a').focus();



   });  
var timer;
$("#aaa input").blur(function () {

    timer = setTimeout(function () {

        $("#aaa").hide()
    }, 50);
}).focus(function(){
    clearTimeout(timer)
});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `$("#aaa input:not(#a)").val('');` to your code for the click event:

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/cBg52/6/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#xxx").click(function () {
        $("#aaa input:not(#a)").val('');
        $("#aaa").show();
        $('#a').focus();    
    });

    var timer;
    $("#aaa input").blur(function () {

        timer = setTimeout(function () {
            $("#aaa").hide()
        }, 50);

    }).focus(function () {
        clearTimeout(timer)
    });
});
```

Comment: 10 mins to go to accept this as an correct answer!!  Thanks SW4  :-)  Please  can you just explain me , what exactly it does...

Comment: Great answer, but I'd rather use the `#aaa input:not(#a)` selector in order to be more precise.

Comment: Hi , Please check this fiddle.http://jsfiddle.net/shrikanth/cBg52/7/  Here first time textbox shows a,b and c respectively. user may change any of this field but i wanted to retain  same values a,b,c only. In that case can we modify this code ??